# How to show value of attributes of child nodes of an element in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How should I show the value contained in the attributes of child nodes of the element?
Please consider below example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Segments>
        <Segment ID="AAA">
            <Elements>

                <Element ID ="11" />

                <Element ID ="22" El/>

                <Element ID ="33" />
            </Elements>
         </Segment>
    </Segments>
```

C# code

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(MyXMLFileLocation);

XmlNodeList xnList = xmlDocument.SelectNodes(/Segments/Segment[@ID='AAA']/Elements);
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    if (xn.HasChildNodes)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode childNode in xn.ChildNodes)
        {

            // How should I fetch the attributes of childnodes here. I have to show the value contained in ID attributes
         }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `childNode.Attributes["ID"].Value;` so you can get its value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);

    XmlNodeList xnList = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("/Segments/Segment[@ID='AAA']/Elements");
    foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
    {
        if (xn.HasChildNodes)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode childNode in xn.ChildNodes)
            {
                string id = childNode.Attributes["ID"].Value;
            }
        }
    }
```